# Label With Dynamic Content - How To Read On Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an `<asp:Label runat="server" />` control on a page whose inner text/html is set using the `Response.Write` shortcut of `<%= foo() %>`.  I would like to get the inner text/html, but am falling short.

I am able to change the syntax of the `<asp:Label runat="server" />` as well, for example `<asp:Label Text='<%=DynamicValue()%>' runat="server" />`.  That particular modification appears to get me nowhere fast, but I am open to others.

Many of these functions are buried deep inside DLLs, but below is a condensed version of what I am trying to do.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
void Page_PreRender()
{
    // how to I get the inner text of SomeLabel?
    Response.Write("SomeLabel.Text: " +
        SomeLabel.Text + "<br>"); // returns blank

    Response.Write("String.IsNullOrEmpty(SomeLabel.Text): " + 
        String.IsNullOrEmpty(SomeLabel.Text) + "<br>"); // returns True

    Response.Write("SomeLabel.Controls.Count: " +
        SomeLabel.Controls.Count + "<br>"); // returns 0
}

string DynamicValue()
{
    return "dyanmic value";
}
</script>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Get Label Inner Text</title>
</head>
<body>
    <asp:Label ID="SomeLabel" runat="server"><%= DynamicValue() %></asp:Label>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page_PreRender occurs before rendering : 
<%= DynamicValue() %>

So there is no way to get the value of SomeLabel using your trick :)

Comment: We are in agreement here, I am just wondering if there is a slick way for me to re-arrange my markup such that I can do what I am trying to do.  The problem is that I am working within an existing framework, so while I can make changes, they are somewhat limited.

Comment: I can't help you more as I don't understand what you want to do exactly, and what is your current limitation ... if you want the value of DynamicValue() just call the function , you don't need to know the innertext of Label... Certainly if it is not previously set as mentioned :=))

Comment: Hmmm... I'm thinking I might go ahead and do something on the server like `SomeLabel.Text = DynamicValue();`.  Kind of weak sauce, but it will get me where I need to be.

Comment: Marking as correct since it appears that what I asked for is not possible.